Have an object serialize itself
With either JSON or Pickle, I can instantiate an object and save that object like so:
import pickle 
thing = Thingy(some_data) # takes a while...
# ... do stuff with thing then save it since it mostly is the same
with open(filename, 'wb') as f: 
    pickle.dump(thing, f)

And read it back if the serialization file exists:
if thingy_file.exists():
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        thing=pickle.load(f)  # Thingy(some_data) restored
    thing.updateyourself()  # pretty fast
else: 
    thing=Thingy(some_data) # takes a while...

However, this serialization is being done externally to the instantiation of Thingy object...
Now suppose I have some custom object with internal data that takes a long time to create:
class Thingy:
   def __init__(self, stuff...)
      # this take a while the first time, but could be instant if read back
      # pseudo'ish:
        if self.file.exists():
            print(f'Existing Thingy {self.file} found...')
            # What I am trying to do here is read from a serialization file the
            # data comprising the last time THIS INSTANCE of Thingy existed
             with open(self.file, 'rb') as f:
                self=pickle.load(f)
        else:
           # bummer this is gonna take a while...
        
        # the rest of the object code...
        # HERE we either have calculated a Thingy or have read it back into itself
        # The instance may be modified -- now save its own self to be re-read in future:
     
    def save_my_own_instance(self):
       # now self is this instance of Thingy that will be serialized to disk
       # magic I do not know...
       with open(self.file, 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(my_own_instance_data, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

So question: What is the method for an object to use serialization to restore its own data into its own instance? What about saving itself inside its own instance?

Some specifics of what is a Thingy:
from pathlib import Path

p=Path(a_HUGE_tree_of_data_files) # 750k plus large image files

tree_data=Thingy(p)
# initial run on p is hour+
# the tree changes very little, so an update of Thingy(p) 
# only takes seconds

# I don't want to educate the user to check for a previous run
# It should be automatic


Alternately, you could make a @classmethod  that looks for a cache file.

One solution to this would be to create a static method in Thingy.
class Thingy:
    @staticmethod
    def load_instance_from_file_or_create_new(filename, stuff):
        if filename.exists():# check if file exists
            with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
                instance=pickle.load(f)
            return instance
        return Thingy(stuff)

    def __init__(self, stuff):
        # create the instance normally

    def __del__(self):
        # the instance is being deleted
        with open(self.file, 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(my_own_instance_data, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

which can be used as
thing = Thingy.load_instance_from_file_or_create_new("xyz",stuff)

The static method loads the Thingy instance from file if the file exists otherwise creates a new instance with the stuff provided.
You will have to store the filename outside the Thingy unless you have a default filename.
And the __del__ method is automatically called whenever an instance is destroyed so you can use that to store the instance into a file.
